# MethodError(f=typeof(Core.Compiler.fieldindex()

Tags: julia

I have the following piece of code where I try to extend the type system by a `TreeStochastic` type.

```
module my_mod



abstract type ScalarVariate <: Real end
abstract type ArrayVariate{N} <: DenseArray{Float64, N} end
abstract type TreeVariate <: Any end

const AbstractVariate = Union{ScalarVariate, ArrayVariate, TreeVariate}

#################### My Types ####################

mutable struct Node
    name::String
    data::Array{Float64,2}
end

mutable struct ScalarLogical <: ScalarVariate
  value::Float64
  symbol::Symbol
end

mutable struct ArrayLogical{N} <: ArrayVariate{N}
  value::Array{Float64, N}
  symbol::Symbol
end

mutable struct ScalarStochastic <: ScalarVariate
  value::Float64
  symbol::Symbol
end

mutable struct ArrayStochastic{N} <: ArrayVariate{N}
  value::Array{Float64, N}
  symbol::Symbol
end

mutable struct TreeStochastic <: TreeVariate
    value::Node
    symbol::Symbol
end

const AbstractLogical = Union{ScalarLogical, ArrayLogical}
const AbstractStochastic = Union{ScalarStochastic, ArrayStochastic, TreeStochastic}
const AbstractDependent = Union{AbstractLogical, AbstractStochastic}


Base.size(v::AbstractVariate) = size(v.value)

function Stochastic(d::Integer)
  if d == 0
    value = Float64(NaN)
    s = ScalarStochastic(value, :nothing)
  else
    value = Array{Float64}(undef, fill(0,d)...)
    s = ArrayStochastic(value, :nothing)
  end
  s
end

function Logical(d::Integer)
  if d == 0
    value = Float64(NaN)
    s = ScalarLogical(value, :nothing)
  else
    value = Array{Float64}(undef, fill(0,d)...)
    s = ArrayLogical(value, :nothing)
  end
  s
end

function Stochastic(d::AbstractString)
  TreeStochastic(Node("",zeros(Float64,(1,2))), :nothing)
end

function Model(; nodes...)
  nodedict = Dict{Symbol, Any}()
  for (key, value) in nodes
    isa(value, AbstractDependent) || throw(ArgumentError("nodes are not all Dependent types"))
    node = deepcopy(value)
    node.symbol = key
    nodedict[key] = node
  end
  nodedict
end

end
```

Upon calling the module and executing the function `Model`, I get an Internal error message:

> Internal error: encountered unexpected error in runtime:
>   MethodError(f=typeof(Core.Compiler.fieldindex)(), args=(my_mod.ArrayLogical{N} where N, :symbol, false), world=0x0000000000000eb9)

The function is called like this:

```
include("f1.jl")
using .my_mod
my_mod.Model(y=my_mod.Stochastic(1),x=my_mod.Logical(2), z=my_mod.Stochastic("t"))
```

If I run the function without `z=my_mod.Stochastic("t")` everything works as expected.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: At first glance this looks like a bug — please report it here: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/new

Comment: And a strange thing is that the error disappears the second time a call is made, so it seems to be compilation-time related.

Comment: Another strange thing I noticed as well: The error does not show when the function is executed through the Juno debugger. I will report it on the official github. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Julia Team the bug should be fixed with Pull request #31670 which is part of Julia 1.2. So using Julia 1.2 or later should fix the issue.